# refresh other page when changes happened on current page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I'm working a project using webview android on inserting quiz question to database. I insert the data to database on page #add. But on the other page #retrieve it doesnt show the result from the database because I havent reload it. The only method that I know is

```
window.location.reload()
```

but it only reload for current page. Are there any method to reload other page?

Comment: If it's for Android, "websockets" is the magic word

Comment: @adeneo but is it suitable for cross platform? since it using webview so it able to be used on other platform as well

Comment: HTML5 EventSource is pretty good choice for this.